# How can I call server side file of my plugin (wordpress) with menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin in wordpress that contain 2 php files. 
In main file , I added two menus and I want to call second php file when user click on second menu. I have a public method that name list_table_page on second file.

```
add_menu_page( 'tm-plug', 'test.php', 'manage_options', plugins_url( 'tm_plug/test.php' ), 'list_table_page' );
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused, are you saying that the code you mentioned calls the 2nd php file that you're looking to see as the user clicks on the second menu? In other words, can you elaborate more on what the code you mentioned exactly does?

Comment: Hi @Sina
Thank you very much.
I have a main menu and a sub menu. but i want to when admin user click on submenu, it show me another page like test2.php.
if you want , I can send you my plugin to you.
Thank you very much

Comment: Alright got you, I posted an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as it's cited in [WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), add_menu_page is defined as:

```
add_menu_page ( string $page_title, //required 
string $menu_title, //required
string $capability, /required
string $menu_slug, //required
callback $function = '', //optional
string $icon_url = '', //option
int $position = null //option
);
```

And the example given is:

```
add_menu_page(
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'custom menu',
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php',
        '',
        plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
        6
    );
```

Which, looking at your code, you're defining the values and parameters wrong. Have a look at below:

```
add_menu_page ( 'tm-plug', //string $page_title
'tm-plug', //string $menu_title
'manage_options', //string $capability
'list_table_page', //string $menu_slug
'tm_plug/test.php', //callback $function = ''
'', //string $icon_url = '' (you haven't defined any)
1 //int $position = null(you haven't defined any)
);
```

Hope by looking at the comments you'd be able to see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: No worries mate, enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**include the file at the to using require_once**

and then call the function of that file (second file ) in the definition of second menu function .

Let me know if you need more help.